# Java Printing: Determine the page that is printing

Tags: java, printing

I have a `print` method below from a class:

```
public void print(EditorPanePrinter epp) {
    try {
        PrinterJob pj=PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        boolean ok = pj.printDialog();
        if(ok) {
            pj.setPageable(epp);
            pj.print();
        }
    } catch (PrinterException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

`EditorPanePrinter` is a `JEditorPane` wrapped with a `JPanel` for print previews. See [here](http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html) for details.

After clicking "OK" from the print dialog shown, the page is printed correctly from the printer.

For more than 1 pages, especially with many pages to print, I want to show a dialog on which pages are printed: i.e. "Printing page 1 of 100" when the 1st page is printing, "Printing page 2 of 100" when the 2nd page is printing, and so on.

I have searched everywhere and I found no solution. How to do this?

If you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Pageable` is made of `Printable`s, when each `Printable` is called, it is passed the `pageIndex` that the system is trying to print, which can used, for example, to print the page number on the output...

See [`Printable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html) for more details.

Depending on the framework you are printing from, you might want to execute this from within a `SwingWorker` and use the `publish`/`process` capabilities to change the active page number.  See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you. I get the idea. Can you please post an SSCCE particularly on how I can obtain the `pageIndex` from `Printable`'s `print()` method to the `doInBackground()` method of `SwingWorker`? From what I know, `pj.print()` method from the code above blocks.

Comment: The `pageIndex` is passed to the `Printable` interface, did you read the linked JavaDocs, it's basic printing 101...

Comment: Thank you for your insights. What I did was to create a wrapper class that extends `EditorPanePrinter` so I can obtain the `pageIndex` and update the dialog to show the page currently printed.

Comment: Since `EditorPanePrinter` isn't part of the base libraries it's difficult to provide more suggestions, but it, itself, must implement `Printable`...